# Spring boot, hibernate - how to get index on entity property?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, annotations

I create an entity object, and annotated it with @Index annotation. Application works, but in database not exist index I want. I tried both JPA and Hibernate annotations with no luck. This class placed in Spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE application. In Maven dependencies I see hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar and it maps to PostgreSQL 9.4.5. I tried different values for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto in application.properties file, like create, create-drop, update and even removed tables from database myself.

Please help: How to make application create index using annotations?

**Update**

I played with annotations and indexes created with same config. I cannot understand what differs. I only find that after I stop my application, and tables created in database it takes some time to see indexes update in pgAdmin. It looks like some cache update or so. Also I find that cannot create index with same name for different tables. Still cannot get what happen.

**Update**

Here entity class

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

@Entity
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "job_id_idx", columnList = "job_id")})
public class JobLifeTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    private Long code;

    @Column(name="job_id", length=24)

    private String targetJobCode;
    @ManyToOne()
    private ScraperTask scraperTask;
    @Column(name="salary_low")
    private Integer salaryMin;
    @Column(name="salary_high")
    private Integer salaryMax;
    @Column(name="scrape_timestamp")
    private Date scrapeTimestamp;
    @Column(name="remove_timestamp")
    private Date removeTimestamp;

    public JobLifeTime(){}

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

Comment: I noticed above that you said Application.properties. Was that just a typo? The file should be named application.properties (notice the lowercase) and it must be placed under src/main/resources for Spring to auto-recognise it

Comment: Yes right - lower case. Application see this file and take config from it. I just miss here when write. Will edit a post.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816817/hibernate-create-index

Comment: Are you using JPA 2.1?

Comment: How should I know JPA version?

Comment: Look at the Maven dependencies?

Comment: Not sure about jars you ask: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar. Or it should be some other jar file?