# how to use the index with springboot or JPA

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, indexing, spring-data-jpa

**Table A**

| ID | shortdescription | thumbnailimage | linkactions | Country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | shortdescription | thumbnailimage | linkactions | E1796BA |

**Table B**

| ID | name | Country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | E1796BA |

**Controller**

```
public ResponseEntity<ContentManagePageVO> queryAllActionsWithPagination(
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNo,
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize,
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String filter) {
return ResponseEntity.ok(contentManageService.queryAllActionsWithPagination(filter, pageNo, pageSize));
    }
```

**Service**

```
   public ContentManagePageVO queryAllActionsWithPagination(String filter, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize,Sort.by("id"));
        Page<ContentCountryDto> contentManagePage;
       if(StringUtils.isBlank(filter)) {
           contentManagePage = contentManageRepository.findAllPaging(paging);
       }else {
           contentManagePage = contentManageRepository.findByTitlePaging(filter, paging);
       }
        if (contentManagePage.isEmpty()) {
            log.error("No record found!!! ", filter);
            throw new GenericSuccessException(StaffNotificationExceptionEnum.CONTENT_MANAGE_PAGE_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION);
        }
        ArrayList<ContentManageVO> ContentManageVOList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ContentCountryDto contentManage : contentManagePage) {
            ContentManageVO contentManageVO = new ContentManageVO();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(contentManage, contentManageVO);
            ContentManageVOList.add(contentManageVO);
        }
        return ContentManagePageVO.builder()
                .page(contentManagePage.getNumber())
                .pageSize(contentManagePage.getSize())
                .result(ContentManageVOList)
                .total(contentManagePage.getTotalElements())
                .build();
    }
```

**Repository**

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Query("select new com.model.entity.ContentCountryDto (A.id, A.position ,A.title,A.shortdescription,A.thumbnailimage, A.linkactions, A.last_updated_date, A.last_updated_by, A.country.countryId, A.country.countryName, A.date_published) " +
            "from ContentManage as A inner join A.country as B where lower(A.title) like lower(concat('%', :filter,'%') ) or lower(A.shortdescription) like lower(concat('%', :filter,'%') ) or lower(B.countryName) like lower(concat('%', :filter,'%')) or lower(A.linkactions) like lower(concat('%', :filter,'%'))")
    Page<ContentCountryDto> findByTitlePaging(String filter, Pageable pageable);
```

I would like to add **index** to retrieve data from the database more quickly.
I have no idea on index, please suggest me how to achieve index in spring boot or JPA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate: Create Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816817/hibernate-create-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of an index by a database engine is almost 100% independent of JPA and Spring Data JPA.

It works simply like this:

You add an index to the table as desired. You do that using SQL for your database and execute it with whatever tool you use to provision your database. Hopefully something like Liquibase or Flyway, but maybe the command line SQL tool of your database.

When a SQL statement gets executed the database will determine (i.e. guess) if the index is helpful for that statement and use it if it deemed helpful. No change of the SQL is necessary.

The basic idea of that estimate is:

- the columns of the index need to be part of the filter criteria used in the table. For an exception for this rule read up on "index skip scan".
- the query needs to return only a small part of the table. Because a full table scan is in most cases faster than accessing 90% of all rows via index access.

Things get more complicated once you get into joins with the many different ways a join can get executed by the database and how these get affected by the presence of an index.